Partition a metric space into parts with small measure and diameter
Consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgure measure $\mu$. It has the property that for any $n\geq 1$, we can partition $\Omega$ into $n$ parts with small measure and diameter. Specifically, given $n$, we can write $\Omega = \cup_{k=1}^n \Omega_k$ with disjoint $\Omega_k$ such that

$\mu(\Omega_k) = \frac{1}{n}$
$diam(\Omega_k) < g(n)$, where $diam(\Omega_k) = \sup_{x,y\in\Omega_k} |x-y|$ and $g(n)$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to \infty} g(n) = 0$

A particular partition is $[0,1] = [0,\frac{1}{n}) \cup [\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}) \cdots [\frac{n-1}{n},1]$.
I am thinking that to what extent can we generalize those two properties to general space. Let's say $X$ is a compact metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and measure $\lambda$. Can those conditions guarantee that we can find partitions with the above properties? If these is not enough, what kind of conditions are needed?

At the very least you'll have to assume $\lambda(X)$ is finite.

That's definitely not enough, you can always pick Dirac delta measure for which $\lambda(\Omega_k) \in {0, 1}$ cannot be $\frac 1 n$.

If a measure is atomless, them if $0<\alpha<\mu(\Omega)$, then there is a measurable set $E$ with $\alpha=\mu(E)$.
